# Custom NavigationBar in swift

Tags: ios

I am very much new to swift and ios so i need my doubts to be cleared for the below concept

I have created a view with a button having background image of back arrow and on button action i am going back to the previous controller which is the Login, is it safe to do it this way instead of using NavigationController??

```
@IBAction func onBackPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let aaa : Login =
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Login")   
    as! Login

    self.presentViewController(aaa, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Use navigation controller and in navigation left bar button you can customize the back button that is the recommended approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation controller is best when you want to push to next **View Controller**.

**(i.e)** Navigation Controller ->View Controller ->View Controller[for Push].

So my suggestion is if you want to come back to previous view controller use Navigation Controller

When you want to present a new **View Controller** that time no need.

Comment: thanx for replying ,what about this 
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) on back pressed

Comment: this is when you present the view controller ,at the time this code needed for dismiss bro @narahari_arjun